# Array is empty using session variables PHP

Tags: php, session-variables, jpgraph

I´m having problems passing an array with float values. It´s empty in the other file. Here´s the code. Please any help...

```
 //file 1 
session_start();
//...
while ($row = pg_fetch_assoc($sql))
{       
    $notas[$i] = ($row['grade'] - 57.3)/12;                 
    $i++;
}

print("<FORM method=post action='../indicadores/distr_notas.php'>");
print("<input type=hidden name=notas value='$notas'>");
print("<INPUT type=submit>");
print("</FORM>");

//file 2
session_start();

$_SESSION['notas'] = $_POST['notas'];
$notas = $_SESSION['notas'];


$cant = count($notas);
echo $cant;
```

I´m still having problems. I think I`m using POST wrong. I have 3 scripts. The first one get the entry, the second one gets the array and the third one shows a graph with the array using jpgraph.

```
file 1 // get the array
<?php  
    print("<FORM method=post action='proc_notas.php'>");
    print("Codigo de Carrera.<p>");
    print("<INPUT type=text name='cod_depto'><p>");
    print("<INPUT type=submit>");
    print("</FORM>");
 ?>


//file 2. 

if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] != "POST")
{
print("<FORM method=post action='normal.php'>");
print("Desviación estándar.<p>");
print("<INPUT type=text name='desviacion'><p>");
print("<INPUT type=submit>");
print("</FORM>");
}
else
{
    $depto = $_REQUEST['cod_depto'];
    $ordenada = array();
    $z = array();
        $i = 0;
        $suma = 0;
    $conectar = new Conector();
    $cadena =  "select distinct a.grade FROM evaluation_student_evals a inner join td_estudiantes b on a.party_id = b.id_estudiante where b.cod_depto = '$depto' and a.grade >= 0 and a.grade <= 100 order by a.grade ";
    $sql = $conectar-> consultas($cadena);      
    //calcular sigma y miu      
    $total = pg_num_rows($sql);
    $sumanotas = new distribucion();
    $totalnotas = $sumanotas -> suma_notas($sql);
    $media = $totalnotas/$total;

//Normalizar datos de notas Z = (X-miu)/sigma
    while ($row = pg_fetch_assoc($sql))
    {       

        $ordenada[$i] = (1/(12*sqrt(pi())))*(exp(-0.5*(($row['grade']-$media)*($row['grade'] - $media))/($desviacion*$desviacion)));                                    
        $i++;   }               

    if (!isset($row))
    {
        header("Content-Type: text/html");
        print("<HTML><HEAD><TITLE>Desempeño de Aprendizaje</TITLE>");
        print("</HEAD>");
        print("<BODY>");
        print("$depto no se encuentra.");
        print("</BODY></HTML>");


//file 3 Graph the array
Here, I don´t know how to get the array $ordenada
```

Comment: you don't put the $notas array in a session

Comment: Thank to all. I founf the problem but not the solution.

Answer (score 0):

This will work with button submission

```
 //file 1 
session_start();
//...
while ($row = pg_fetch_assoc($sql))
{       
    $notas[$i] = ($row['grade'] - 57.3)/12;                 
    $i++;
}

print("<FORM method=post action='../indicadores/distr_notas.php'>");
print("<input type=hidden name=notas value='".implode(',' $notas)."'>"); // use implode to convert array to string
print("<INPUT type=submit>");
print("</FORM>");

//file 2
session_start();

$notas = explode(',' $_POST['notas']);  // use explode to convert string to array

$cant = count($notas);
echo $cant;
```

And this will work with session

```
//file 1 
session_start();
//...
while ($row = pg_fetch_assoc($sql))
{       
    $_SESSION['notas'][$i] = ($row['grade'] - 57.3)/12;                 
    $i++;
}

print("<FORM method=post action='../indicadores/distr_notas.php'>");
print("<input type=hidden name=notas value='$notas'>");  // no need to use
print("<INPUT type=submit>");
print("</FORM>");

//file 2
session_start();

$notas = $_SESSION['notas'];


$cant = count($notas);
echo $cant;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 $_SESSION['notas'][] = ($row['grade'] - 57.3)/12;
```

Answer (score 0):

In the first file you set `$notas` array, but in the second you use `$_POST['notas']` to add it to session variables, then assign to `$notas`. The count in the second file is `0`, because you do not count the elements of array generated in the first file, but instead you count elements of one of the values passed by `POST` request (stored in `$_POST` array).

To sum up: **you create one array, but count elements of different one**.

Depending on how you invoke the second file (is it a different request? is it included from the first one?), you have following options:

A. (if it is a different request) Assign `$notas` variable to the session array element like that:

```
// at the end of the first file:
$_SESSION['notas'] = $notas;
```

and in the second file read from it instead from `$_POST['notas']`, or

B. (if the second file is included from the first one) Use the same name of the variable as in the first file (`$notas`) and assign it instead of `$_POST['notas']`:

```
// in the second file, instead of " $_SESSION['notas'] = $_POST['notas']; "
$_SESSION['notas'] = $notas;
```

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to make some calculations to the query result in file 2 before to send it to jgraph at file 3. I still don´t know why this part doen´t work:

//file 2

```
$depto = $_REQUEST['cod_depto'];
$desviacion = $_REQUEST['desviacion'];
$ordenada = array();
$i = 0;
$suma = 0;
$conectar = new Conector();
$cadena =  "select distinct a.grade FROM evaluation_student_evals a inner join td_estudiantes b on a.party_id = b.id_estudiante where b.cod_depto = '$depto' and a.grade >= 0 and a.grade <= 100 order by a.grade ";
$sql = $conectar-> consultas($cadena);      

//calcular sigma y miu          
$total = pg_num_rows($sql);
$sumanotas = new distribucion();
$totalnotas = $sumanotas -> suma_notas($sql);
$media = $totalnotas/$total;

//Normalizar datos de notas Z = (X-miu)/sigma
while ($row = pg_fetch_assoc($sql))
    {       
        $ordenada[$i] = (1/($desviacion*sqrt(pi())))*(exp(-0.5*(($row['grade']-$media)*($row['grade'] - $media))/($desviacion*$desviacion)));                                      $i++;
    }
$tmp= serialize($ordenada);
$tmp= urlencode($tmp);
echo "<form method=post action='../indicadores/distr_notas.php'>";
echo "<input type=hidden name=ordenada value=$tmp>";
echo "<input type=submit name=enviar>";
echo "</form>";
```

I decide to comment the part "calcular sigma y mui" and now, I can pass the array to file 3.

//file 3

```
function array_recibe($url_array) {
    $tmp = stripslashes($url_array);
    $tmp = urldecode($tmp);
    $tmp = unserialize($tmp);

   return $tmp;
} 

$notas =$_REQUEST['ordenada'];
$notas =array_recibe($notas);

//jpgraph code
$graph = new Graph(600,400,"auto");
```